# Pattern matching or Map Monads

Tags: scala

I was wondering what do you guys think is more idiomatic and better in terms of performance.

Over a monad of type Option or Try, use pattern matching or map and getOrElse in case you want to control the side effect.

So what do you think is better this:

```
maybeConnectTimeout
  .map(connectTimeout => session.connect(connectTimeout))
  .getOrElse(session.connect())
```

Or this

```
maybeConnectTimeout match {
  case Some(connectTimeout) => session.connect(connectTimeout)
  case None => session.connect()
}
```

Comment: You can use `fold` to blend together the `map` and `getOrElse` - In general, it is recommend to prefer HoF over pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks I completely forgot the fold, and is sooo elegant. Thanks man!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez can you please write it as an answer?

Comment: @James i mean, the question should be closed for being opinion based anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what ... is ... better in terms of performance.

According to [odersky](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/449td4/fold_or_pattern_matching_with_an_option/czp154s?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) pattern match

> I am surprised that the pattern match gets so little love here. Not only is it by far the fastest (probably at least 10 times as fast as the alternatives), it is also the clearest.